# What's wrong with my docker IPv6 network?

Tags: docker, networking, ipv6

I have an issue with my docker containers that I can't figure out.
The containers are connected by a network which allows both IPv4 and IPv6 to be used:

```
root@ad46a51c5c21:# docker network inspect f9313031ab32
[
    {
        "Name": "my_net",
        "Id": "f9313031ab329c809d16879ef4276c00181e83c0521a3b5220043ecbede4db7f",
        "Created": "2019-07-03T17:05:26.774007984+02:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": true,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.16.238.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "172.16.238.1"
                },
                {
                    "Subnet": "2001:3984:3989::/64",
                    "Gateway": "2001:3984:3989::1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "Containers": {
            "ad46a51c5c21f807fd6aef4bc4aa2c44107ac5a1740af8187063352ae8eabd20": {
                "Name": "docker_MyContainer_1_1",
                "EndpointID": "cb61aab8cf60ab19527600fd198be56a0b20b7b00e391c5601b3de9bae535bf9",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:10:ee:66",
                "IPv4Address": "172.16.238.102/24",
                "IPv6Address": "2001:3984:3989::102/64"
            },
            "fb1ab6c8bef37a05ef3de840baaa033ef8281011ba65c9341165381f08646642": {
                "Name": "docker_MyContainer_2_1",
                "EndpointID": "7f91c31799ecc052e86aef77dacbe8f6010f30cc78dfabe22b8bde4962913945",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:10:ee:8e",
                "IPv4Address": "172.16.238.142/24",
                "IPv6Address": "2001:3984:3989::142/64"
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

A server is running in the container, which is listening for connections:

```
root@ad46a51c5c21:# netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:42047        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11/sshd             
tcp6       0      0 :::11880                :::*                    LISTEN      26/pserver        
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      11/sshd             
udp        0      0 127.0.0.11:51591        0.0.0.0:*
```

I interpret the output above as the IPv4 traffic is routed through the IPv6 sockets, since there is no IPv4 socket listening on port 11880.

The server can be accessed locally on port 11880 using both IPv4 and IPv6:

```
root@ad46a51c5c21:# pclient 172.16.238.102   
userid:"MyUser"
root@ad46a51c5c21:# pclient 2001:3984:3989::102   
userid:"MyUser"
```

But from a remote container on the same host, the server can only be reached using IPv4:

```
root@fb1ab6c8bef3:# pclient 172.16.238.102
userid:"MyUser"
root@fb1ab6c8bef3:# pclient 2001:3984:3989::102
<nil> rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure
```

The remote container can ping the server container using both IPv4 and IPv6:

```
root@fb1ab6c8bef3:# ping -c 2 172.16.238.102
PING 172.16.238.102 (172.16.238.102) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.16.238.102: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.268 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.238.102: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.137 ms

--- 172.16.238.102 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.137/0.202/0.268/0.067 ms

root@fb1ab6c8bef3:# ping -c 2 2001:3984:3989::102
PING 2001:3984:3989::102(2001:3984:3989::102) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2001:3984:3989::102: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.219 ms
64 bytes from 2001:3984:3989::102: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.218 ms

--- 2001:3984:3989::102 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.218/0.218/0.219/0.014 ms
```

Any idea why my server can't be reached using IPv6 from the remote container?

Comment: What linux container base image are you using? Check that ipv6 is enabled at that level (on Alpine, `grep ipv6 /etc/sysctl.conf` should show `net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 0`).

Comment: golang1.13.3 is the base image. I don't see that setting at all in sysctl.conf. Does it mean that it's 0 or 1? Would ping still work for IPv6 if that setting was set to 0?

Comment: ping uses the ICMP protocol, not TCP. You can use `nmap` instead to check TCP v4 and v6 access. Eg: `nmap -6 -p 11880  docker_MyContainer_1_1`. Remove the `-6` to check for ipv4 instead. The docker daemon IP resolver will translate your docker container name into its IP.

Comment: Thanks. I googled this setting and I got the impression that if it would have been set (=1), the containers wouldn't have had any IPv6 addresses (which they have).  Would netstat have reported tcp6 in case ...disable_ipv6 was set?

Comment: But there are definitely interesting stuff in the output from the nmap commands:
...
Nmap scan report for docker_MyContainer_1_1 (172.16.238.102)
...
PORT      STATE SERVICE
11880/tcp open  unknown
...

...
Nmap scan report for docker_MyContainer_1_1 (2001:3984:3989::102)
...
PORT      STATE    SERVICE
11880/tcp filtered unknown
...

Comment: BTW: These are the values set in my containers:

`# sysctl -a | grep disable_ipv6
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.disable_ipv6 = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth1.disable_ipv6 = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 0`
I assume those are OK(?), since the interface specific settings are set to 0.
Setting all to 0 didn't solve the pclient issue.

Comment: `tcp filtered unknown` means that a firewall or something is blocking access and nmap can't access that port. Check that ipv6 is enabled on both the host and the docker container. Your docker container is based on golang1.13.3 which is Debian so use `sysctl -a|grep disable_ipv6`. If your host is Ubuntu you can use the same command.

Comment: I've verified that IPv6 is enabled on the host as well. Any other ideas?